# table to store huge data

Tags: sql-server

Does any one have idea about storing email boby in the sql server. The email body is about 15 lines. what has to be done inorder to maintain a table with 40 different emails contents.

Example:
  a : some cotent should be sent
  b : some other content

---

Comment: What exactly is the problem? 15 lines of email body isn't likely to be that much and I doubt you'd get over 4000 characters which is the limit in SQLServer 2000. So what do you need to do that can't be done with standard SQL? Maybe if you tell us what your actual specific problem is we can help more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want an `nvarchar(max)` column to store the contents of the body. This allows you to store up to 2GB worth of text...which is kind of a lot of text, so you should be good.

Comment: Yeah, this would work but I'd be surprised if 15 lines of e-mail requires a max to work...

Comment: Yeah, without much other guidance, I'd have to say `max` for email bodies, especially with the way the reply chains can keep getting added. But you are correct, 15 lines of readable text should be well south of 4000 characters.

Comment: So Eric and chris.So you mean to say I can Do this way.        CREATE TABLE TBLEMAIL(code char(1), DESC varchar(255), emailContent nvarchar(max))                                                      Can you please provide one example with insert into. As i not aware like how to insert that email content

Comment: CREATE TABLE dbo.[Mail]
    ([Code] CHAR(1) null,[Description] varchar(255) null,[EmailContent] nvarchar(max) null)

    INSERT INTO [DW03DB].[dbo].[test]
    ([Code],[Description],[EmailContent])
    VALUES(<Code, char(1),>,<Description, varchar(255),>,<EmailContent, nvarchar(max),>)

Comment: @user993935 - Insert it like you would normally insert text: `INSERT INTO TBLEMAIL('A', 'This is an email', 'Oh man, look at this awesome email. You can go on and on and on and on in this thing!')`. Where are you getting the email from and how are you planning on retrieving it? Last I tried, you couldn't use SQL Server to read an email server.

Comment: Example: I have emial body in this way.                           "You are receiving this emial becasue you have not the paid your credit card bill and crossed the the limitation on amount. So please check all bill payments and their dates in order to get appreciation and extra amount. get a detailed report blaaa....blaaa ........blaa.....................................................                                                     how do i need to insert while inserting into table?

Comment: I'm not planning to retrieve it from source. i just need to maintain  in table and  send that emial when button is clicked in the front end

Comment: You should be able to insert it just like you would another `nvarchar` column, like your `Description` or `Code` columns. There's not special syntax that you need to use.

Comment: create table tb1                                              (  id int  primary key, name varchar(255), mainterm nvarchar(max))  I'm getting an error Incorrect syntax near max? Can any one advise me?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? On 2005+ at the very least, that completes without an issue.

Comment: I'm using 2008  SQL Management studio

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5891/discussion-between-user993935-and-eric)